# What the <T> means in BeanFactory.java in spring?

Tags: java, spring

I'm reading the spring source code, the BeanFactory.java have a method:

```
<T> T getBean(Class<T> requiredType) throws BeansException;
```

the second T is the return type, but what's the first  mean?

Comment: that really answered my question, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the method has a type parameter. WHen you call it with an object of type `Class<T>` then it returns an object of type T.

The first T is an indication that the T is a type parameter.